# Prove that every operator G such that GT = TG is a polynomial in T

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $T:V \rightarrow V$ ($\dim V \lt \infty$) a diagonalizable operator with the algebraic multiplicity of eigenvalues ​​$1$. Then every operator $G$ such that  $GT = TG$ is a polynomial in $T.$

My attempt:

I Know that if $GT = TG$ then the eigenspace of $T$ is G-Invariant.

In fact, let $v$ an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, by assumption

$T(G(v)) = G(T(v)) = \lambda G(v)$ $\Rightarrow$ $G(v)$ is eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

What I do with this?

Comment: Which means that $G(v)= \alpha v$ for some $\alpha$, since $\langle v\rangle$ is the eigenspace of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$...

Comment: ok, I get it, so we have a restection $T \restriction_{Aut(\lambda)}: Aut(\lambda) \rightarrow Aut(\lambda), v \longmapsto G(v) $ and I know that the minimal polynomial of restection divide the minimal polynomial of T, but why G is a polynomial in T?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{Aut}(\lambda)$? I thought $\lambda$ was an eigenvalue, that is, a scalar. What is the automorphism group of a scalar?

Comment: sorry, in my country we define  $Aut(\lambda)$= {$ v \in V; T(v) = \lambda v$}

Comment: That’s called the eigenspace associated to $\lambda$. A common notation is $E_{\lambda}$. But the fact that the eigenspace is $T$-invariant is independent of anything else you have here. My point is that the eigenvectors of $T$ are also eigenvectors of $G$.

Comment: Hint:Find a polynomial $P$ that takes $\lambda$'s to $\alpha$'s.  Show that $G$ is that polynomial of $T$.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is diagonalizable. So it is easiest if just change basis to one where $T$ is diagonal.

All eigenvalues have multiplicity $1$, so all diagonal entries are distinct. This means that any matrix which commutes with $T$ is also diagonal in this basis (so the subspace of endomorphisms $V\to V$ which commutes with $T$ has the same dimension as $V$).

Also, all diagonal entries of $T$ are distinct, so $I, T, \ldots, T^{n-1}$ are all linearly independent. Therefore the subspace of endomorphisms $V\to V$ consisting of polynomials in $T$ has the same dimension as $V$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! you rock!